# Javascript Extensibility

Tags: javascript

I've a script, which manipulates with canvas. I call it like this:

```
namespace.module.do(canvas, paramString);
```

I'd like to move the call to the canvas itself, so it'll somewhat similar to:

```
<canvas namespace.module.dobehavior=paramString />
```

Can I do it with `JS` and if not how close can I get to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("canvas[ns.mod.colorBehavior]") {
        var color = $(this).attr("ns.mod.colorBehavior");
        if (color == "red") {
            var context = this.getContext('2d');
            context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
            context.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
        }
    }
}
```

Where width and heigh are the width and height of your canvas element (or a higher value like 10000).

Answer (score 1):

The canvas is a DOM object, so you could attach functions to it. In your example:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].namespace.module.dobehavior = function(paramString) { ... code ... };
```

(obviously, document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].namespace and document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].namespace.module would need to be an object, so you might need to do

```
document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].namespace = { module : { dobehavior : function(paramString) { ... } } };
```

And then if you had the canvas element somewhere (possibly also through `var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];`) you could do

```
canvas.namespace.module.dobehavior("someString");
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Kinda, my ultimate aim is to avoid calling JS but rather extend functionality by attaching new behavior, for example <canvas ns.mod.colorBehavior = "red" /> should fill canvas with red by calling js under the hood.